# Hybrid K8S accross on-prem and public cloud

Tags: kubernetes, hybrid

I'm running my service at K8S on-prem, is there any way to deploy my service (such as an eComm website) accross K8S on-prem and public cloud's K8S (for example Google Compute Engine run K8S or GKE) as hybrid K8S?

Can K8s (or Istio) support this kind of requirement for two different location?

Comment: Anthos supports this I think, but I've never tried (or even used Anthos in general).

Comment: Could you specify more details about external service option ? @HarshManvar

Comment: checkout spinnaker which is used for cross cluster k8s deployments

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly the answer is yes.

According to the [GKE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/gke-on-prem/docs/overview).

> GKE On-Prem is hybrid cloud software that brings Google Kubernetes
>   Engine (GKE) to on-premises data centers. With GKE On-Prem, you can
>   create, manage, and upgrade Kubernetes clusters in your on-prem
>   environment and connect those clusters to Google Cloud Console.

You can find the Overview of installation [here](https://cloud.google.com/gke-on-prem/docs/how-to/installation/install-overview). And rest of the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/gke-on-prem/docs/).

As for [Istio](https://cloud.google.com/gke-on-prem/docs/how-to/add-ons/istio):

> Istio is an open source framework for connecting, monitoring, and
>   securing microservices, including services running on **GKE On-Prem**.

Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @OhHiMark, from my understanding, GKE On-Prem (Now calls Anthos on-prem) is a core component of Anthos, which  required paid / trial subscription from Google. I would like to know is that before Anthos released, is there any similar solution to achieve Hybrid K8S across on-prem and the cloud?

Comment: Is it possible to deploy service between on-prem and the cloud on K8S without Anthos?

Comment: There are some [alternatives](https://stackshare.io/google-anthos/alternatives) but I am afraid that they are not free either. [Here](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3428108/the-major-hybrid-cloud-options-compared-aws-outposts-vs-azure-stack-vs-google-anthos.html) you can find an interesting article comparing the most major options.